# Убрать разделители элементов списка ListView

Tags: android, listview

```
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Серые полоски, видимо глюк стиля, как убрать их? как сделать их невидимыми. там 1 px вроде.

И еще хотелось бы получить от вас статью хорошую по разборке стилей. Такиъ как кнопки или listView и  т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в разметку `ListView` вот это:

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Comment: Я уже решил проблему добавив #fff )), но в прнципе это тоже варант). 

Мне вот интеренстно они там тестят что - нибудь когда что - то добавляют в андроид студию? 

Вместо того чтобы этот стиль исправить по молчанию сделать 0px, они завтра новый компонент выпустят с 0px, и sdk еще на пару кило будет больше весить))

Comment: @xTIGRx ваша проблема в том, что вы с чего то взяли, что все должно быть, как хотите вы, а остальное - глюк, баг  и тд. Причем ваши представления в корне отличаются от общепринятых. В списках ДОЛЖНЫ БЫТЬ разделители, нравиться вам это или нет.

Comment: @pavlofff Полностью с вами согласен, парень много о себе думает. В особенности, что он всегда прав и хамит тем, кто доказывает обратное